# On order of $5$ dozen boxes of a product, a retailer receives extra dozen free. What is the equivalent discount for offer?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions, finance, percentages, word-problem

On an **order** of **$5$ dozen boxes** of a consumer product, a **retailer receives** an **extra dozen free**. This is equivalent to allowing him a discount of:

1. $15\%$
2. $\frac{97}{6}\%$
3. $\frac{50}{3}\%$
4. $20\%$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for every 5 dozen he orders, he gets 1 dozen free. This is equivalent of paying for only $\frac{5}{6}$ of your order, therefore, $\frac{1}{6}$ discount.

To convert this to percentage we multiply by 100 to get $\frac{1}{6} \times 100 = \frac{50}{3}$.

So the answer is 3.